# Problem using if statement with multiple conditions to substitute factors in dataframe (R)

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have a data frame quiz that looks like this

```
Participant  Group  Test  Marks
1             1      Qz1   2.4
1             1      Qz2   3.2
1             1      Qz3   2
1             1      Qz4   1
2             1      Qz1    3
2             1      Qz2   4
2             1      Qz3   3
2             1      Qz4   4
3             2      Qz1   4
3             2      Qz2   2
3             2      Qz3   3
3             2      Qz4   2
```

Assume all columns are as factors except for quiz$Marks.

I would like to create another factor column quiz$zip using something like this:

```
if ((quiz$Group==1) & (quiz$Test=='Qz2'| quiz$Test == 'Qz4'))
     {quiz$zip<-3}
else if ((quiz$Group==1) & (quiz$Test=='Qz1'| quiz$Test == 'Qz3'))
     {quiz$zip<-2}
else
     {quiz$zip<-1}
```

I cannot make it work, and other than the fact that it is late at night, I cannot find a reason.

Your help and enlightenment is much appreciated!

Comment: `if` and `else` work on single values. You gave them entire vectors. (And it used only the values in the first row. You should have gotten warning messages. `ifelse` works on entire vectors. For once this problem is _not_ related to using factor variables. And if you had succeeded it would have been a numeric column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested `ifelse`

```
transform(df, zip = factor(ifelse(Group == 1 & Test %in% c('Qz2', 'Qz4'), 1, 
                            ifelse(Group == 1 & Test %in% c('Qz1', 'Qz3'), 2, 3))))
```

Or `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(zip = factor(case_when(Group == 1 & Test %in% c('Qz2', 'Qz4') ~ 1, 
                                Group == 1 & Test %in% c('Qz1', 'Qz3') ~ 2, 
                                TRUE ~ 3)))

#   Participant Group Test Marks zip
#1            1     1  Qz1   2.4   2
#2            1     1  Qz2   3.2   1
#3            1     1  Qz3   2.0   2
#4            1     1  Qz4   1.0   1
#5            2     1  Qz1   3.0   2
#6            2     1  Qz2   4.0   1
#7            2     1  Qz3   3.0   2
#8            2     1  Qz4   4.0   1
#9            3     2  Qz1   4.0   3
#10           3     2  Qz2   2.0   3
#11           3     2  Qz3   3.0   3
#12           3     2  Qz4   2.0   3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Participant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), Test = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Qz1", 
"Qz2", "Qz3", "Qz4"), class = "factor"), Marks = c(2.4, 3.2, 
2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The nested ifelse did the trick. I ended up using a variation of what is suggested above, using

frameName$newFactor<- with(frameName, ifelse (cond1 & cond2 %in% c('Qz2', 'Qz4'), frameName$newFactor<-1, ifelse....))

Answer (score 0):

You should have seen an error message like `Bedingung hat Länge > 1 und nur das erste Element wird benutzt` - probably on english. It says that your *if* finds more than one element, but will only use the first.

You can overcome this easily by using `tidyverse` and `mutate` and put `ifelse` loops into this. Through `mutate` the designation from `ifelse` will be assigned to a column for those rows, for which the condition is true.

You have to be a bit careful, as the the first `ifelse` contains in the second place - where the value for the *FALSE* would be used - a second `ifelse` condition. I have chosen to put `0` in, if none of the both conditions is TRUE.

```r
library(tidyverse)

quiz <- tribble(
  ~Participant, ~Group, ~Test, ~Marks,
    1,  1,  'Qz1',   2.4,
    1,  1,  'Qz2',   3,
    1,  1,  'Qz3',   2,
    1,  1,  'Qz4',   1,
    2,  1,  'Qz1',   3,
    2,  1,  'Qz2',   4,
    2,  1,  'Qz3',   3,
    2,  1,  'Qz4',   4,
    3,  2,  'Qz1',   4,
    3,  2,  'Qz2',   2,
    3,  2,  'Qz3',   3,
    3,  2,  'Qz4',   2
  )


quiz <- quiz %>% mutate(quiz = ifelse((quiz$Group == 1) & (quiz$Test == "Qz2" | quiz$Test == "Qz4"), 3,
  ifelse((quiz$Group == 1) & (quiz$Test == "Qz1" | quiz$Test == "Qz3"), 2, 0)
))
quiz
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    Participant Group Test  Marks  quiz
#>          <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1           1     1 Qz1     2.4     2
#>  2           1     1 Qz2     3       3
#>  3           1     1 Qz3     2       2
#>  4           1     1 Qz4     1       3
#>  5           2     1 Qz1     3       2
#>  6           2     1 Qz2     4       3
#>  7           2     1 Qz3     3       2
#>  8           2     1 Qz4     4       3
#>  9           3     2 Qz1     4       0
#> 10           3     2 Qz2     2       0
#> 11           3     2 Qz3     3       0
#> 12           3     2 Qz4     2       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>